# I need to ignore the text of a select and use just the numeric value, I am using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

I am learning Vue and decided to make a simple tax calculator with the result showing in real time (without a show total value button), everything is fine but I have a select and and ideally you will be able to see the type of tax and the value, however, I can only make it work with just the value.

```
<select ref="taxEs" class="form-control" v-model="settings.tax" @change="saveChanges()" onfocus="this.select()"> 
        <option>tax1, 6.25%</option>
        <option>tax2, 8.90%</option>
        <option>tax3, 8.25%</option>
        <option>9.25</option>
```

So only the last option(9.25) works, how can I put the description but make vue to only use the value.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you give them values, like `<option value="6.25">tax1, 6.25%</option>`?

Comment: I have a similar thing that looks like `<option v-for="category in categories" :value="category">{{category.text}}</option>` The select itself is just  `<select name="category" v-model="category">`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a value on the . 
Something like this:

```
    <option val="6.25">tax1, 6.25%</option>
    <option val="8.9">tax2, 8.90%</option>
    <option val="8.25">tax3, 8.25%</option>
    <option val="9.25">9.25</option>
```